# How does a queryset knows what records are in the database if it doesn't hit the database

Tags: django, database, django-queryset

Django querysets are lazy

```
person_set = Person.objects.all()
```

In the documentation it says the above code doesn’t run any database queries. 
But with the above command it generates a queryset in this case person_set and this object contains all the person objects.

```
 person_set = Person.objects.all()

 print(person_set)
```

This is the output.

```
 <QuerySet [<Person: Person object (7)>, <Person: Person object (8)>, <Person: Person object (9)>]>
```

If it didn't hit the database then how does it know that what records are in the database? As it is supposed to run queries only when it is evaluated using a loop or others methods.

Answer (score 0):

Printing the queryset is evaluating it, to build the string representation of the object.

Comment: So queryset is basically just a raw sql. Is it?

Comment: It's more, but yes, at some point it gets translated into a SQL query that is send to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all of the situations where a QuerySet hits the database here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

One of them is `repr()`, which is called when you print the queryset.